# Как поменять стиль только для главной страницы в joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

*Joomla 3.7*, раньше работало так: поставить в параметры страницы -> в поле css класс страницы - > указываем стиль, 
а в *template.css* уже добавляем стиль, который хотим. Но сейчас почему-то это у меня не работает. Может я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой же вопрос данным способом, все очень просто,нужно скопировать шаблон (не дублировать а именно скопировать), и затем просто отметить страницы или модули(если есть) для нужного шаблона.